# What does "Mus. Reg. Gall." stand for?

Tags: abbreviations

Gibbon, at the end of a [note](https://archive.org/details/historyofdecline55gibb/page/212/mode/2up) detailing the imprinting on a medal, has "(Mus. Reg. Gall.)".

I have found other references outside Gibbon, and have gotten (maybe) as far as "Mus. Regis Galliar.", found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=AW4eYPquc2MC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=mus.%20regis%20galliar&source=bl&ots=GCZZLRirDZ&sig=ACfU3U397H7EbB5mrvoGbJWGa1vwtS5W6g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHjfPU9efuAhVZV80KHWfnBAAQ6AEwEHoECBEQAg#v=onepage&q=mus.%20regis%20galliar&f=false), but no further.

What do the "Mus." and "Galliar." stand for?

Comment: Could be Museum Regis Galliarum, the French royal museum where the medals are kept? I don't know which that would be in Gibbon's day, presumably not the Louvre.

Comment: Based on [a page from another book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Descrizione_degli_Stateri_antichi_illust/I2CVL25oXsUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22mus.+reg.+gall.%22&pg=PA33&printsec=frontcover), it definitely seems to be a reference to some French museum. My guess is either "Regional Museum of France" or "Royal Museum of France."

Comment: Presumably it would be Museo Regis Galliarum in that case; it's possible, but I only found one reference to that, and I would expect more (but my expectations could obviously be incorrect). I had found that page from another book, but that just multiplied the references to what I already had, it didn't help me with what the words were.

Comment: Wiki fr has a list of French museums. There are two 'Gaillards.' The commune on the Swiss border has a decorative tower. The Normandy Gaillard has a Royal Castle which is a cultural centre and museum. Select Fr as language choice in the left margin before searching.